# All images are the same size

Tags: c#, asp.net

For some reason every HTML image that I add to any page seems to somehow be linked to the rest by size. This is on any page. I thought maybe the ID of the element had to be changed, but that didn't seem to resolve this.

So what happens: resizing an image on one page or in one location on a page resizes all of the rest on all of the other pages across the entire site. I can use different pics though.

My biggest problem if this has already been asked is not knowing what to Google. :(

Answer (score 2):

Probably in the CSS file you have something like this 
`img{ width: 50px ; height: 50px }`

Just remove that line.

Comment: Well your certainly not wrong, it is adding that to my bootstrap.css file (I'm using visual studio). But any time I modify one image, it adjusts that height and width in the css file. If I remove it, everything looks fine.... until I modify the size of an image again and it puts those values back in there. Have you seen this before?

Comment: Ok... You can add a class like<br>
`.img2{
  width: 12px !important;
  height: 12px !important;
}`<br>
And put that class into IMG tag like `class='img2'`

Comment: Understood, I've used CSS before. :) I've developed web pages. Usually, I can just set the size properties in the image <img src="" height=10 width=10> (that's just from memory, I can't remember the exact code. Nevertheless, the problem I'm facing is visual studio keeps trying to do this through CSS but I want it done just on the image itself. I"m so baffled with why VS is trying to change css for every single image.